# Open a popup after successfully submitting form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, popup, popupwindow

I am working on a Smoke Quit Pledge signup form where there are three pledge options.

1. Cut down and smoke less than 10 cigarettes a day
2. Have no cigarettes for 3 weeks
3. Quit smoking cigarettes

I want, when someone input correct info in the form and successfully submit it, he/she should get a pledge card download link in a popup window. There are 3 pledge card for 3 options. People should get pledge card for what option they select.

I have the working form that sent data to database when form is submitted. But can't get it done as described above.

How I an do this?

Thanks
Azizul

Comment: Do you need help with code or logic? Your question is to broad. StackOverflow isn't really the place to discuss possible design solutions either, and is frowned upon. Also, you are not supplying any example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You already know what the user selected. Show a popup on successful
   submit.
2. Have your page display something depending on what the server sends
   back after successful form post

This is all we can help you with. Your question is too vague.